# How to read image stored in azure storage by using url

Tags: file-upload, azure-storage, image-rendering

I upload the image by using azure blobclientservice as belows

```
 let fr = new FileReader();

  let result = {};

  fr.onload = async function () {
    var data = fr.result;

    await blockBlobClient
      .uploadData(data, {
        concurrency: 20,
        blobHTTPHeaders: {
          blobContentType: photo.type,
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        result = res;
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        result.error = true;
      });
  };
  fr.readAsArrayBuffer(photo);
```

And I got the url from the response successfully.
I hope to use this url as the src in image tag in html instead of download all data from the storage.
But it doesn't show the image and I can only see alt instead of image.
I think it is possible to read the image by using url when it is stored in aws s3 bucket as public.
I want the same functionality in azure storage.
Is it possible?
I will be appreciative if somebody helps me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your image should be able to show on your page with:

```
<img src="the_url_of your_image">
```

You could access blob with Blob URL(`https://{storage-name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container-name}/{test.png}`) when your image blob is public.

[image]

If the access level is private, you could access the image blob with [SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delegate-access-with-shared-access-signature). And the URL looks like `https://{storage-name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container-name}/{test.png}?{Blob SAS token}`.

Try to generate Blob SAS token with [generateBlobSASQueryParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/?view=azure-node-latest#generateBlobSASQueryParameters_BlobSASSignatureValues__StorageSharedKeyCredential_).

```
// Generate service level SAS for a blob
const blobSAS = generateBlobSASQueryParameters({
    containerName, // Required
    blobName, // Required
    permissions: BlobSASPermissions.parse("racwd"), // Required
    startsOn: new Date(), // Optional
    expiresOn: new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 86400), // Required. Date type
    cacheControl: "cache-control-override", // Optional
    contentDisposition: "content-disposition-override", // Optional
    contentEncoding: "content-encoding-override", // Optional
    contentLanguage: "content-language-override", // Optional
    contentType: "content-type-override", // Optional
    ipRange: { start: "0.0.0.0", end: "255.255.255.255" }, // Optional
    protocol: SASProtocol.HttpsAndHttp, // Optional
    version: "2016-05-31" // Optional
  },
  sharedKeyCredential // StorageSharedKeyCredential - `new StorageSharedKeyCredential(account, accountKey)`
).toString();
```